# Add the dataframes by a group and divide by that number of occurences

Tags: python, dataframe, data-manipulation

Lets say i have the following dataframes of different lengths:

```
  name  value
0    a    4.0
1    b    6.0
2    c    5.0
```

```
  name  value
0    a    4.0
1    b    2.0
```

```
  name  value
0   c    3.0
```

how would I add them together and then divide by the amount of occurences? Final dataframe below:

```
  name  value
0    a    4.0 = (4+4)/2 
1    b    4.0 = (6+2)/2
2    c    2.67 = (5+3)/3
```

Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have 3 DataFrames you can concat them together, take a groupby and return mean.

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
df.groupby('name')['value'].mean().reset_index()
```